# separable equation1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does this solve the Impartible Equation is correct?

Impartible Equation:

$(x+1)y'y=y^2-1$

solve:
$y'=y^2-1/y(x+1)$

$f(x,y)=y^2-1/y(x+1)$

$y^2-1/y/(x+1)/1$

$f(x,y)=(y^2-1)/y/(x+1)/1$

$y^2-1=M(x)$
,
$(x+1)/1=N(y)$

Comment: What is an "Impartible Equation"?

Comment: I mean  "Impartible Equation" is =>  If so that is the first order y ′ =f(x,y) differential equation: f(x,y)=M(x)/N(x)We call the integral differential equation

Comment: *I mean "Impartible Equation" is =>*... No idea what you are talking about. Sorry. Maybe you could use a more standard terminology?

Comment: I'm sorry that I could not express it well
I mean is: separable equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential equation $(x+1)y'y =y^2-1$ is **separable**. Rewrite it as $$\frac{y}{y^2-1}y'=\frac{1}{x+1}.$$
On the left we recognize the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}\ln(|y^2-1|$. Integrating, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(|y^2-1|)=\ln(|x+1|)+C.$$